# projecting the map in rviz using map_server

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, gmapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use map_server as in this link:

wiki.ros.org/map_server

I built my map using mapper3 (basic)

the map should be projected in Rviz grid and should occupy it all, the centre of the map using mapper3 ( basic) should be the centre of the Rviz grid.

The problem is that the map is always shifted (the centres are not the same ) The centre of Rviz grid is the left down corner of the map image ( the image only occupy one quarter of the grid). How can I fix this problem?

Also, I have the error of No transform from [map] to [odom]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147451/projecting-the-map-in-rviz-using-map_server/) by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing you could do is manually edit the origin of the map in the yaml file. See http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format

**EDIT:** Could you update your question to include the launch file(s) you are using. Moreover, what is the fixed_frame of rviz set to?

**EDIT2:** It actually sounds like there is no transformation from your fixed frame to the frame_id of your map. Try chaning the fixed frame in rviz to `map`, or whatever your map's frame_id is.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on 2014-04-05**:
The ymal file has the following
image: testmap.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0

I tried to change the origin to [-10 -10 0] or tp [10,10,0] but nothing changed, it gives the same result.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-27**:
I too facing the problem did you fix it and how?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2016-01-27**:
See my edit above.